# Spark 2.2.0 on AWS EMR writing to Parquet drops rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

So I have an issue where by certain rows in a DataFrame get dropped when writing to partitioned Parquet files.

Here are my steps:

1. Read CSV data files from S3 with specified schema
2. Partition by 'date' column (DateType)
3. write as Parquet with `mode=append`

First step of reading works as expected, no parsing issues. For quality checks I do the following:

For a particular partition for `date='2012-11-22'`, perform a count on CSV files, loaded DataFrame and parquet files.

Here's some code to reproduce using pyspark :

```
logs_df = spark.read.csv('s3://../logs_2012/', multiLine=True, schema=get_schema()')
logs_df.filter(logs_df.date=='2012-11-22').count() # results in 5000
logs_df.write.partitionBy('date').parquet('s3://.../logs_2012_parquet/', mode='append')
par_df = spark.read.parquet('s3://.../logs_2012_parquet/')
par_df.filter(par_df.date=='2012-11-22').count() # results in 4999, always the same record that is omitted
```

I have tried writing to HDFS too and result is same. This happens on multiple partitions. There are no records in default/null partition. `logs_df` above is accurate and correct.

Second experiment I tried was to write an unpartitioned parquet files. The only difference in above code was omission of `partitionBy()`:

`logs_df.write.parquet('s3://.../logs_2012_parquet/', mode='append')`

Loading this parquet set and running a count as above yielded the correct result of 5000 for `date='2012-11-22'` and other dates. setting mode to `overwrite` or not setting (using default) results in same data loss.

My environment is:

- EMR 5.9.0
- Spark 2.2.0
- Hadoop distribution: Amazon 2.7.3
- Tried with both EMRFS consistent view and not. However most testing was done writing to HDFS to avoid any S3 consistency issues.

I would very much appreciate a fix or workaround or another way of converting to parquet files using Spark.

Thanks,

Edit: I was not able to reproduce the second experiment. so let's say both partitioned and unpartitioned seems to drop records when writing to Parquet or JSON.

Comment: Is it always the same record which is missing? Is the date well-defined for all the records in your dataframe?

Comment: Yes it's the same one. The date is formatted correctly. The DataFrame contains the record as I can identify it using `filter()`. So it is always at the write step when using partitionBy that it goes wrong.

Comment: Any ideas why certain rows get dropped on writing to hdfs or s3? I tried this with columns as STRINGs too. Can't figure out why.

Comment: also as an experiment tried to write out JSON files and reading back, same rows get dropped :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the mystery was definitely in the schema definitions. However, unexpectedly it wasn't dates or timestamps. It was in fact boolean values.

I had exported the CSV from Redshift which writes bools as `t` and `f`. When I inspected the inferred schema those fields were marked as string types. A simple test with `true` and `false` in a CSV file recognised them as boolean.

So I was expecting date and timestamp parsing to go wrong as usual but it was booleans. Lesson learnt.

Thanks for the pointers.